# How to count akkaHttp RejectionHandler rejections and successes?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to count rejects that were returned by RejectionHandler
I guess the way I doing this now is not the best one, or even incorrect. I am just trying to invoke the incremental method in my database, in each of the handled cases.

```
  implicit def rejectionHandler: RejectionHandler =
    RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
      .handle {
        case MissingCookieRejection(cookieName) =>
          requestInfoEntry.incrementRjectedNum
          complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = "No cookies, no service!!!"))
      }
      .handle {
        case AuthorizationFailedRejection =>
          requestInfoEntry.incrementRjectedNum
          complete((Forbidden, "You're out of your depth!"))
      }
      .handle {
        case ValidationRejection(msg, _) =>
          requestInfoEntry.incrementRjectedNum
          complete((InternalServerError, "That wasn't valid! " + msg))
      }
      .handleAll[MethodRejection] { methodRejections =>
        requestInfoEntry.incrementRjectedNum//todo sideeffect ??
        val names = methodRejections.map(_.supported.name)
        complete((MethodNotAllowed, s"Can't do that! Supported: ${names mkString " or "}!"))
      }
      .handleNotFound {
        requestInfoEntry.incrementRjectedNum
        complete((NotFound, "Not here bldghad!"))
      }
      .result()
```

While I "visit my unfound page", Akka HTTP returns me a right response: "Not here bldghad!" every time I refresh browser on not existed web-page. But when I check my database, I see the only one increment. Can I do this way as I do at all? (I need to count successes too)

PS Maybe I need to work with status codes and do not use side effects. But what is the best place where I can do it? I  have a lot of controllers and do not want to intercept this in every controller)

Can I globally intercept responses somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way, hope it would be useful

```
  def rejectionHandlerWithCounter: RejectionHandler = { (rejections: Seq[Rejection]) =>
    requestInfoEntry.incrementRjectedNum
    Some(complete((StatusCodes.Forbidden)))
  }
```